# Spring Boot Thread management

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am barely new with Spring framework and i would like to ask opinion of the experts.

It is a spring boot application with a rest end point, which everytime is called it will put an action on a queue that will be consumed by a thread.

The way I am organizing my code is:

Application class
A runnable class.
A component class.

The component class has the  annotatiion @Component and it only contains an instance for the thread.

```
@Component
public class ComponenteExample {
    @Autowired
    Runnable runnableImpl;
    Thread thread;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
       thread = new thread(runnableImpl);
       thread.start();
    }
```

What I would like to ask if there is a better/elegant way to manage this thread. By this I mean if it could be Spring container to manage it?

Comment: Use an executor? (And use constructor injection instead of field injection; it's more manageable.)

Comment: What is the overall purpose if this thread / runnable construct? If you want an async worker you really can use the `@Async` annotation on a `void` (or `Future<ResultType>`) method and spring magically does things for you, including threads and queues. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async also in bsmk's answer. [Reactor](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/13/reactor-a-foundation-for-asynchronous-applications-on-the-jvm) would be a framework for elaborate async processing systems.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The purpose is to process a XML under request, but the processing should be asynchronous and due to memory constraints shall be processed one XML at a time (if a new request arrives, then should be put on the queue).

Answer (score 3):

For asynchronous call you can use https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

However if you want to use queues you should look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms

And for event-driven application there is https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/